# how Querying Dijango date save on JSONField

Tags: python, mysql, django

i save multi date in json filed.

example:

```
row 1 : [ "2022-10-26", "2022-11-10" , "2022-11-16", , "2022-11-17"]
row 2 : [ "2022-09-26", "2022-09-10" , "2022-09-16"]
row 3 : [ "2022-12-16" ]
```

How i can filter date bigger than `2022-10-01`?
**
in the example i must get row 1 & 3

Comment: Please *don't* save dates in a JSON blob. Use a model with a `ForeignKey`: relational databases are typically *not* very good with JSON blobs.

Comment: Can you show us the model that has the JSONField please?

Comment: thanks @WillemVanOnsem . i create relational databases